# How to align a table of display nicely

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to create a script that act as a ps command with it's own properties that I want to display. Say this is how processes would look like in ps command:

```
sas 24431     1  0 Oct10 ?        00:51:08 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Denv=DEV -Dapp.name=myApp -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Dlog.dir=/apps/java/logs
```

I want to display as below:

```
UID  PID    APPNAME
sas  24431  -Dapp.name=myApp
sas  24432  -Dapp.name=myApp2
sas  24433  -Dapp.name=myApp3
```

**Note:** the `app.name` property is a command argument that is extracted from the ps command

This is my script:

```
echo -e "PID\tUSERID\t\tAPPNAME"
ps -u $USER -f |grep "java"|grep -v "grep"|
while read LINE 
do 
  #Get pid from the line
  PID=$(cut -d" " -f2 <<< $LINE);
  #Get parameter value called "-Dapp.name or -DprojectName" 
  #from the ps command for the process
  APPNAME=$(ps -f $PID | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "}; /-Dapp.name|-DprojectName/');
  USERID=$(cut -d" " -f1 <<< $LINE);

 echo -e $PID"\t"$USERID"\t"$APPNAME;
done;
```

Right now  it works the way I want it. But sometimes the alignment getting screwed. Also can this script be optimized into one line command?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would use `printf`, rather than `echo`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also can this script be optimized into one line command?

I'd consider using the `-o` option of the `ps` command to output (as far as possible) only the fields of interest, and then post-processing that to match the `java` processes and specific command argument(s) that you require - something like

```
ps -u $USER -o uname=,pid=,args= | 
  gawk -vOFS='\t' '/java/ {print $1,$2,substr($0,match($0,"-D(app[.]name)|(projectName)[^[:space:]]*"),RLENGTH)}'
```

or perhaps something like this in `perl` (*DISCLAIMER: my perl knowledge is sketchy*)

```
ps -u $USER -o uname=,pid=,args= | 
  perl -anle 'print join "\t", @F[0], @F[1], grep /-D(app[.]name)|(projectName)/,@F if /java/'
```

Comment: Do you know why in gawk the -D(app[.]name) doesn't show the value? it only display "-Dappname". But for -DprojectName works fine. Any idea?

Comment: @Sas Oops it looks like my regex was incorrect - try `match($0,"-D((app[.]name)|(projectName))[^[:space:]]*"),RLENGTH)` i.e. extra parentheses aroud the `((app[.]name)|(projectName))`. Likely the same mistake affects the `perl` expression.

Comment: It works, but do you know why in the process list I also see the regex search as a process: "Sas 7344    projectName)[^[:space:]]*"),RLENGTH)}". Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: @Sas the usual trick for that is to change something in the command from a literal character to a regular expression so that the process does not match itself e.g. change `projectName` to `[p]rojectName`or `/java/` to `/[j]ava/`. Unfortunately I can't test that as I don't have the exact processes in my ps output.

Answer (score 13):

For general purpose tabular alignment, you want the `column` utility.

For example:

```
(
 printf 'PID\tUSER\tAPPNAME\n'
 printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "1" "john" "foo bar"
 printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "12345678" "someone_with_a_long_name" "pop tart"
) | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Results in:

```
PID       USER                      APPNAME
1         john                      foo bar
12345678  someone_with_a_long_name  pop tart
```

Comment: to avoid subshell, we can use `{ cmd;}`

Comment: To expand on @RahulPatil's comment, `{printf ...;}` is marginally more efficient than `(printf ...)` because `()` spawn a child process, while `{}` doesn't. This becomes relevant if the command is used in an inner loop, because then it can spawn thousands of child processes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one using the output formatting from `ps`:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh -f
printf '%-8.7s%-8s%s\n' $(
     ps -o uname=UID,pid=PID,args=APPNAME | 
     sed -n '1p;s/\( [0-9]* \).*\(-Dapp.name=[^ ]*\).*/\1\2/p'
)
```

Based on its format string, for every 3 of its arguments `printf` will print:

1. The first space-padded on the right to a standard tab-width of 8 characters and truncated to a maximum of 7 characters.
2. The second space-padded on the right to a standard tab-width of 8 characters.
3. And then the third followed by a `\n`ewline.

The command substitution is *not* quoted *on purpose*. Note the `-f` following `sh` in the bang-line - it specifies that the shell should *not* glob - so there is no danger of randomly generating filenames based on shell special characters. The command substitution will be split on `$IFS` defaults - space, tab, newline.

Within the command substitution `ps` prints 3 columns - headed with **UID**, **PID**, and **APPNAME**. `ps` is POSIX-specified *not* to print any spaces in any field *excepting* the `args=` field. So the first two columns are `$IFS` safe. Still, in order to get the `-Dapp.name` string out of the `args=` field it must be processed.

So `sed` filters it. On lines containing at least two spaces and the string *-Dapp.name=* it prints:

1. The first sequence of a space then zero or more numbers then a space and all that precedes it...
2. The last occurring sequence containing the string *-Dapp.name=* followed by all characters before the next occuring space.

`sed`'s substitutions do not affect the column headings - printed w/ `1p` - because they don't contain the *-Dapp.name=* string. All other lines are deleted from output.

After applying `printf` to `sed`'s output split on `$IFS` you can expect output like the following:

```
UID     PID     APPNAME
sas     24431   -Dapp.name=myApp
sas     24431   -Dapp.name=myApp
sas     24431   -Dapp.name=myApp
sas     24431   -Dapp.name=myApp
sas     24431   -Dapp.name=myApp
```

In my opinion, though, this `sed` statement would work a little better:

```
sed -n '1p;s/\( [0-9]* \).*-Dapp.name=\([^ ]*\).*/\1\2/p'
```

It is basically the same, except that strips the *-Dapp.name=* portion from `\2` so it prints like...

```
UID     PID     APPNAME
sas     24431   myApp
sas     24431   myApp
sas     24431   myApp
```

Because, since it's *only* printing lines containing the *-Dapp.name=* sequence anyway, including it is kind of just clutter that can otherwise be taken for granted.